# Sybase SQL QUERY - error while executing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

When I try to execute this stored procedure im getting this error"Database Connector Error: 'Implicit conversion from datatype 'CHAR' to 'INT' is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query" how come? how can I fix this?  thanks

this is the query im using to execute the SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc2(@store char(4))
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE stor_id=@store
END

exec TestProc2 @store = "7066"
```

---

```
sp_help stores

stor_id,     char,       4
stor_name,   varchar,    40
stor_address,varchar,    40
city,        varchar,    20
state,       char,       2
country,     varchar,    12
postalcode,  char,       10
payterms,    varchar,    12
```

the column is set as char(4) so I don't think there is a mismatch with the query and data types

BTW I tried("7066") with single quotes, with double and without quotes, I still get the same sql error. please help

PS Im using sybase thanks! also below is a screenshot of the error.

any other info you guys need to help me? thanks

http://tinypic.com/r/2n24huq/8

Comment: Edit your question and include the query that is failing.

Comment: Just a hunch.. try single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: I tried with singule quotes, with double and without quotes, I still get the same sql error. please help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `stor_id` field in the `stores` table is an `int`.  Change your stored procedure to accept an `int` instead of a `char(4)`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc2(@store int)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE stor_id=@store
END
```

Comment: Thats the problem also it set in the column as char(4), everything matches I don't know why it gives error

Comment: @user3558483 -- Can you run `sp_help stores` and post?  Would like to see your table definition.